# Separating pieces of a pie chart

Tags: java, awt, pie-chart

I have code to draw a piechart of equal sections. But I don't want each slice of pie to be attached to each other, but rather have a distance (space) between each slice.  How do I do this?

```
import javax.swing.JApplet;
import java.awt.*;

public class PieChart extends JApplet {
    public void paint(Graphics page) {
        setBackground(Color.lightGray);

        page.setColor(Color.blue);
        page.fillArc(70, 25, 100, 100, 0, 45);

        page.setColor(Color.yellow);
        page.fillArc(70, 25, 100, 100, 45, 45);

        page.setColor(Color.black);
        page.fillArc(70, 25, 100, 100, 90, 45);

        page.setColor(Color.green);
        page.fillArc(70, 25, 100, 100, 135, 45);

        page.setColor(Color.red);
        page.fillArc(70, 25, 100, 100, 180, 45);

        page.setColor(Color.magenta);
        page.fillArc(70, 25, 100, 100, 225, 45);

        page.setColor(Color.cyan);
        page.fillArc(70, 25, 100, 100, 270, 45);

        page.setColor(Color.orange);
        page.fillArc(70, 25, 100, 100, 315, 45);
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all, never draw directly within a JApplet's paint method as by drawing within a top-level window, you risk bad side effects in the child components and borders. Instead draw within the paintComponent method of a JPanel that is then displayed within your JApplet. Next you will want to call the super's painting method within your override, else your GUI won't do necessary housekeeping painting including clearing "dirty" pixels. Next, avoid hard-coding your numbers as you're doing as that leads to inflexible difficult to debug and enhance code.

Comment: Reasonable advice for a real program, but there is merit to minimizing non-question content in a question...

Answer (score 0):

As hagello suggests you'll probably want to "explode" the pie by moving the pieces out from the center.  To do this you'll want to compute the direction of (the center of) each wedge.  And then move the origin of your wedge some distance in this direction.  Here's a possible calculation of those remapped x & y coordinates:

```
public class pie {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            int x;
            int y;
            int d = 5;             /* our distance of "explosion" */

//          thing.fillArc(70, 25, 100, 100, 0, 45);   /* we had (70,25) */
            x = offsetX(70, d, 0, 45);
            y = offsetY(25, d, 0, 45);
//          thing.fillArc(x, y, 100, 100, 0, 45);     /* with new x & y */
            System.out.println("x = " + x + ", y = " + y);  /* showing */
    }

    public static int offsetX ( int x, int d, int sa, int aa ) {
            double  ca  = Math.toRadians((sa + aa) / 2.0);

            return x + (int)(Math.cos(ca) * d);
    }

    public static int offsetY ( int y, int d, int sa, int aa ) {
            double  ca  = Math.toRadians((sa + aa) / 2.0);

            return y + (int)(Math.sin(ca) * d);
    }
}
```